# GLSurfaceView OnTouchEvent never called

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin, gesture, glsurfaceview

In my Xamarin Android application I created an Activity with custom GLSurfaceView  on it. The layout is following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Hi! I am model viewer!" />
    <test.ui.droid.controls.ModelViewerGLSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom `ModelViewerGLSurfaceView` (derived from GLSurfaceView) is needed for OpenGL rendering and works just fine.

Now I want to add gesture recognition. In order to do that I overridden OnTouchEvent in my ModelViewerGLSurfaceView, but this function is never called, no matter what I do.

However when I override OnTouchEvent on parent Activity, it works.

Why OnTouchEvent is never called for my GLSurfaceView?

Comment: Can you show how your method looks? The method name is actually `onTouchEvent()` (note lower case `o`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance forget to register the onTouchListener?

You need to call setOnTouchListener on your view to register the callback.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)